# How to add class friends on different files headers?

Tags: c++, friend

My class **Bloque** is a friend of my other class **user** and i want to pass an `int y` of my **user** class to a function called `void colision()` on my *Bloque* class.

So I tried this:

```cpp
# user.h #

class user
{
    private:
        int y;
    friend class Bloque;
};

# bloque.h #

class user;
class Bloque
{
    public:
        void mover();
        void colision(user& f);
};

# bloque.cpp # 

#include "user.h"
#include "bloque.h"
#include <iostream>

void Bloque::mover(){ colision(user& f); }

void Bloque::colision(user& f){ cout << f.y; }
```

When i try to compile it, i get two errors:

````
In member function 'void Bloque::mover()':
bloque.cpp [Error] expected primary-expression before '&' token
bloque.cpp [Error] 'f' was not declared in this scope
Makefile.win    recipe for target 'bloque.o' failed```
````

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And then learn how to create a [mcve] to show us. Lastly please edit your question to include the *full* and *complete* error output, including any possible informational notes. And copy-paste the build output with the errors, as text of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [forward declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class#Forward_declaration) looks correct.

The problem is in this line:

```
void Bloque::mover() { 
   colision(user& f); 
}
```

Your variable `f` does not exist. I don't understand what you are trying to do exactly. If you are planning to call `Bloque::colision` with a variable of `user` type you should first declare it:

```
void Bloque::mover() { 
   user us;
   colision(us); 
}
```